# AngularJS 1.x depends validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-1.6

I'm having following three input fields;

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" 
    placeholder="Work Phone" class="form-control" 
    data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone"  
    data-ng-required="!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone 
    || addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone)"/>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" 
    placeholder="Mobile Phone" class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone" 
    data-ng-required="!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone 
    || addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone)"/>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="pager_phone" id="pager_phone" 
    placeholder="Pager Number" class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone" 
    data-ng-required="!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone 
    || addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone)"/>
```

and the following two select boxes;

```
<select name="primary_communication" id="primary_communication" class="form-control" 
data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication" 
data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
    <option value="">Select Primary Communication</option>                                                    
</select>

<select name="secondary_communication" id="secondary_communication" class="form-control" 
data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication" 
data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
    <option value="">Select Secondary Communication</option>                                                    
</select>
```

The above select boxes take the following array of objects as values;

```
self.communicationTypes = [
{code: "CMPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Mobile Phone"}
{code: "CWPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Work Phone"}
{code: "CPNO", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Pager Number"}
{code: "CEMA", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Email"}
]
```

The validation that I'm in need is like when I select any option from primary communication select box say 'Mobile Phone' and if the input field for the mobile phone is not provided with any values I need to display an error message below that input field. Similarly for other options as well. The same effect i want on secondary communication also.

**Note:** I have already used ng-required on mobile, work & pager input fields for another validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the inputs in a form and do the validations. Check if the `ng-model` of select is either mobile, work or pager phone to enable required field for corresponding inputs

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var self=this;
self.communicationTypes = [
{code: "CMPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Mobile Phone"},
{code: "CWPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Work Phone"},
{code: "CPNO", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Pager Number"},
{code: "CEMA", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Email"}
]
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as addCareAdminController">
    <form name="phoneForm">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" placeholder="Work Phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CWPH'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CWPH'" />
        <span style="color:red;" ng-if="phoneForm.work_phone.$error.required">Work phone is required</span>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CMPH'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CMPH'" />
        <span ng-if="phoneForm.mobile_phone.$error.required" style="color:red;">Mobile phone is required</span>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="pager_phone" id="pager_phone" placeholder="Pager Number" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CPNO'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CPNO'" />
        <span style="color:red;" ng-if="phoneForm.pager_phone.$error.required">Pager phone is required</span>
        <span style="color:red;" ng-if="!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication)&&!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone)">Please fill at least 1 of these fields. </span>
        <select name="primary_communication" id="primary_communication" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication" data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
            <option value="">Select Primary Communication</option>
        </select>

        <select name="secondary_communication" id="secondary_communication" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication" data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
            <option value="">Select Secondary Communication</option>
        </select>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: This is working, but I have already used ng-required for another validation and its displays a different error message.

Comment: Already used ng-required for another validation and its displays a different error message?  You can change the above errors to whatever you want.@karthi

Comment: I'm using `ng-required="!(addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone || addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone)"` for another validation and it's corresponding error message is `<div class="error" data-ng-message="required">Please fill at least 1 of these fields.</div>`. In this how can i intergrate yours.

Comment: The above is for which input field?

Comment: For all the three input fields (mobile, work & pager). I'm having the above validation.

Comment: You have to change the validations from the above to something like in the answer. You can directly check which input is required or not instead of checking indirectly. but if you want to show only one error message , then check if the form is valid or not

Comment: I need two kinds of validations here. The one I have implemented checks whether one of three input fields(mobile, work & pager) is present. The other one is what I have asked as a question.

Comment: Is your select mandatory? If so then by default the above validations will take care of the first one.Otherwise try the updated answer and see

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="login-form" name="Form" id="Form" ng-controller="AddCareAdminController as addCareAdminController" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && addCareAdminController.save()" novalidate>
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" placeholder="Work Phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.workPhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CWPH'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CWPH'" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CMPH'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CMPH'" required="true"/>
     <span class="text-danger" ng-show="Form.$submitted && Form.work_phone.$error.required"><b>Enter valid Work Pager</b></span>

     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.mobilePhone" data-ng-required="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication=='CPNO'||addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication=='CPNO'" required="true"/>
     <span class="text-danger" ng-show="Form.$submitted && Form.mobile_phone.$error.required"><b>Enter valid Mobile Phone</b></span>

     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="pager_phone" id="pager_phone" placeholder="Pager Number" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.pagerPhone"/>
     <span class="text-danger" ng-show="Form.$submitted && Form.pager_phone.$error.required"><b>Enter valid Page Phone</b></span>

     <select name="primary_communication" id="primary_communication" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.primaryCommunication" data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
       <option value="">Select Primary Communication</option>                                                    
     </select>
     <span class="text-danger" ng-show="Form.$submitted && Form.primary_communication.$error.required"><b>Select primary communication</b></span>

     <select name="secondary_communication" id="secondary_communication" class="form-control" data-ng-model="addCareAdminController.careAdminModel.secondaryCommunication" data-ng-options="type.code as type.description for type in addCareAdminController.communicationTypes">
       <option value="">Select Secondary Communication</option></select>
     <span class="text-danger" ng-show="Form.$submitted && Form.secondary_communication.$error.required"><b>Select secondary communication</b></span>
</form>
```

> Your controller Code:-

```
  var App = angular.module('App', []);
  App.controller('AddCareAdminController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  var self=this;
  self.communicationTypes = [
    {code: "CMPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Mobile Phone"},
    {code: "CWPH", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Work Phone"},
    {code: "CPNO", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Pager Number"},
    {code: "CEMA", groupCode: "COMM-METH", description: "Email"}
   ]
 }]);
```

> Note: This validations fire on form submit.